# Windows 11 (and Chrome) doesn't allow me to associate torrent magnet files

Tags: google-chrome, bittorrent, file-association, transmission, magnet-links

I'm using Transmission on Windows 11 and whenever I click on a magnet file in Chrome (which uses the OS file associations), I get the popup:

[image]

But when I go under `Settings > Apps > Default apps` in Windows, I don't see anything called `magnet` under either `Choose defaults by file type` or `Choose defaults by link type`.

I've also tried looking at `regedit`, but I don't have the key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Magnet\shell\open\command
```

What should I try next?

Comment: From within transmission settings, there is no option to associate the protocol with it? Also, if you don't have the ```HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Magnet\shell\open\command``` key, you can simply add the key and create the values

Comment: Not sure about Transmission, but qBitttorent has setting to associate magnet and torrent files with the app.